How to stop testNG run programmatically?
I have this code to start a selenium tests
private ExecutorService ex;
    private List<String> testngXmlFiles;
    private TestNG testNG;

    public TestNGRunner(List<String> testngXmlFiles) {
        this.testngXmlFiles = testngXmlFiles;
        this.testNG = new TestNG();
    }

    public void runTests(){
        TestListenerAdapter listener = new TestListenerAdapter();
        testNG.addListener(listener);
        testNG.setTestSuites(testngXmlFiles);
        testNG.run();
    }

public void stop() {
        testNG.getSuiteListeners().forEach(listener -> {
            if (listener instanceof TestListenerAdapter) {
                ((TestListenerAdapter) listener).onFinish(null);
            }
        });
    }

I have a GUI to start the tests by clicking on a button and I need to make a function to stop the tests, I have tried many methods however it just stop the current test and immediately open the next one
I will show you the part which I run the tests from GUI
runButton = new JButton("Run Tests");
        runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                testThread = new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        // Update TestNG.xml with selected scenarios
                        TestNGRunner.TestNGUpdater(selectedScenarios, "TestNG.xml");

                        // Redirect console output
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
                        PrintStream oldOut = System.out;
                        System.setOut(ps);

                        // Run the tests using the updated TestNG.xml
                        List<String> testngXmlFiles = List.of("TestNG.xml");
                        testngRunner = new TestNGRunner(testngXmlFiles);
                        testngRunner.runTests();


                        // Restore console output
                        System.out.flush();
                        System.setOut(oldOut);

                        // Display output in consoleTextArea
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> consoleTextArea.setText(baos.toString()));
                        // Execute Allure generate command
                        ProcessBuilder allureBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "allure generate --single-file --clean");
                        allureBuilder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "target"));
                        Process allureProcess = allureBuilder.start();
                        allureProcess.waitFor();

                        // Open the Allure report
                        File htmlFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "target/allure-report/index.html");
                        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                            runButton.setEnabled(true);
                            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                        });

                    }
                });

                testThread.start();
            }
        });

this code edit the testNG.xml file to include the tests which the user has chosen from the UI and then run the thread and below I will show you the code to stop execution however as I said it just stops the current running test and then the next test will open
 stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (testThread != null && testThread.isAlive()) {
                    // Interrupt the testThread to stop execution
                    testngRunner.stop();
                    testThread.interrupt();
                    try{
                        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f");
                        Process process = builder.start();
                        process.waitFor();

                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    } finally {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                            runButton.setEnabled(true);
                            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                        });
                    }

                }
            }

        });

as you can see I'm trying to call the stop function and then interrupt the thread
so does anyone can advice me on how to stop the test execution
when I close the application the test execution stop (if this might help)
